# Django form error when queryset is changed to none or subset

Tags: django-forms, django-queryset, htmx

I am working on a dependent dropdown using htmx in Django. Since the dataset is very large I do not want to load all the data in the beginning, and only load the data as required dynamically using htmx. The form working fine when I set the queryset as Model.objects.all() but since it takes a long time to load initially, I changed the queryset to Models.objects.none() or Models.object.all()[:xx] so there is no or minimum data. The form work as expected and the dependent dropdown work nicely, but when I submit the form there is an error saying "Select a valid Choice. That choice is not one of the available choices."
My question is does .all() return different objects than .none() or all()[:xx]? If not what cause the error? I have spent hours trying to find the cause of the errors but to no avail. I want to know what cause the error.

Here is the models.py

```
class Province(models.Model):
    province_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    province_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class City(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_code = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    city_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Address(models.Model):
    province = models.ForeignKey(Province,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Here is the forms.py

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addreess
        fields ='__all__'
        widgets = {
            "province": form.Select(
                attrs={
                    "hx-get":"import/load-city/",
                    "hx-target":"#city",
                    "hx-trigger":"change",
                    "hx-swap":"innerHTML",
                }
            ),
            "city": form.Select(
                attrs={
                    "id":"city"
               }
            ),
         }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super(AddressForm, self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
         self.fields["province"].queryset = Province.objects.all()
         self.fields["city"].queryset = City.objects.all()  
         ## comment: error if .none() or .all()[:xx]
```

Here is the views.py

```
class AddressCreateView(CreateView):
     model = Address
     form_class = AddressForm
     template_name = 'address_create.html'
     success_url ='/'

class LoadCityView(View):
     def get(self,request):
         if request.GET.get("province"):
             province = request.GET.get("province")
         else:
             province=None
         cities = City.objects.filter(province=province)
         context = {"cities":cities}
         return render(request,"load_cities.html",context)
```

Here is the urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('address-create/', AddressCreateView.as_view(), name='address-create'),
    path('load-city/', LoadCityView.as_view(), name='load-city'),
]
```

Here is the template

address_create.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1"></script>
        <script>
            document.body.addEventListener('htmx:configRequest', (event) =>
             {
                 event.detail.headers['X-CSRFToken'] = '{{csrf_token}}';
             })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

load_cities.html

```
<option value="">------------</option>
{% for city in cities %}
<option value="{{city.id}}">{{city.city_code}} {{city.city_name}}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. [edit] your code, select the code fragments and click on the "Code sample" button (`{}`) to format the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the queryset, set the `.choices` to empty, this will prevent *rendering* the items, but still do the validation properly:

```
class AddressForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Addreess
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {
            'province': form.Select(
                attrs={
                    'hx-get': 'import/load-city/',
                    'hx-target': '#city',
                    'hx-trigger': 'change',
                    'hx-swap': 'innerHTML',
                }
            ),
            'city': form.Select(attrs={'id': 'city'}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['city'].choices = []
```

this will still validate the item with the `.queryset` that contains all items, and thus will make *filtered* queries to the database, but omit *rendering* these choices.

What you are trying to do, lazy loading items with AJAX has been wrapped in a package named [**`django-select2`** <sup>[readthedocs.io]</sup>](https://django-select2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it might be better not to reinvent the wheel, and let the package handle this.

---

> **Note**: Since [**PEP-3135** <sup>[pep]</sup>](https://peps.python.org/pep-3135/), you don't need to call `super(…)` with parameters if the first parameter is the class in which you define the method, and the second is the first parameter (usually `self`) of the function.